# Поиск по файлам

Tags: массивы, поиск, php

Добрый день.
У меня есть вопрос, как организовать цикличный поиск по ключам в файлах средствами php.

Приведу пример: есть у меня папка html в ней еще папки и html файлы, у меня есть ключи в массиве что-то типо того

```
$arr = array('text1', 'text2', 'text3');
```

Как мне просканировать  все эти файлы и директории на наличие ключей из массива, с определением в каком файле оно найдено, и в какой строке.
Буду вам очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте в цикле открытие файлов для чтения. Поиск в файле preg_match . Если искомый текст найден в файле записывайте имя файла в отдельный массив.

Comment: но как определить в какой строке он найден?

Comment: Что именно Вы подразумеваете под "в какой строке" ? Порядковый номер строки в файле? Или вся строка целиком (строка между переносов) ?

Comment: порядковый номер строки

Comment: По функциям определения порядкового номера строки на ум ничего не приходит. Как вариант считывать каждый файл построчно, а не целиком. Итерация цикла в которой сработает поиск preg_match и будет номером строки. Но такой вариант будет затратен по времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вызывайте системную функцию **grep** и разбирайте результаты - там будет и номера строк, и вхождения